# Filter by polymorphic associations thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filtering, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have the following models.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timeline_items, :as=>:subject

  define_index do
    ....?
  end
end

class TimelineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject, :polymorphic=>true
  belongs_to :actor, :polymorphic=>:true
end
```

I want to get all the posts belonging to specific actors with thinking-sphinx.

In `ActiveRecord` I would do like

`Post.where('timeline_items.actor_type = "User" AND timeline_items.actor_id IN [1,2,3]).includes(:timeline_items)`

My question is what indexes have to define and what query have to use to get the same results with thinking-sphinx?

**Update**
However I also need to filter the posts by different actor types like:
`Post.where('timeline_items.actor_type = "Group" AND timeline_items.actor_id IN [1,2,3]).includes(:timeline_items)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following a try:

```
define_index do
  # ...
  has timeline_items.actor.id, :as => :actor_ids
end
```

And then for searching:

```
Post.search 'foo', :with => {:actor_ids => [1,2,3]}
```

As detailed in the comments, if you need to filter on a specific class's values in those polymorphic associations, then you're going to need to create another association for just that class. This is because Sphinx has no concept of hashes/key-value pairs, and so can't track which ids belongs to which classes.

Once you have that new association in place, then add an attribute for that much like above - perhaps like this:

```
has user_timeline_items.actor.id, :as => :user_actor_ids
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the issue is that I can have duplicate ids because its a polymorphic association. For example if I can have `actor_type="User" and actor_id=1` and also `actor_type="Group" and actor_id=1` so i need to filter by the `actor_type` scoped to `actor_id`

Comment: Oh, I see. No easy way to deal with this - Sphinx has no concept of key-value pairs.

Comment: If you could create a separate association that had the extra conditions (user_actors, perhaps), then add attributes via that instead, then it may work?

Comment: Yes, that was the solution I came up with. Please update your answer so I can accept it.